# How to apply Formatted Mask to a input filed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to apply Formatted Mask to my input box. Here I have jsFidle for Doller currency, But instead of doller I need to change Soles(S/.), For that I have overriden the `$locale`.

this is the code i have overiden in jsfidle.

```
$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.CURRENCY_SYM = S/.
```

Soles symbol is visible but while entering number amount there is a problem.

Here is the fidel. I dont know how to post fidle link. There is condition to post jsfidle. Here I am posting url. Please find it.  http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/xKrYp/

**UPDATE:-**
My requirement is I want a soles symbole before my value that is I achieved through annoop answer.Even ng-model is not effecting for the first time,But The problem I am facing with that is if I edit the existing value it is effecting to my ng-model.

My second problem is I am having two text boxes.In one text box I need to show doller and second I need to show soles symbol. If I apply this script in my jsp page I am only getting soles, Not soles. If I Remove that script from jsp I am getting only soles not doller.

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.4/i18n/angular-locale_es-pe.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have an error in your jsfiddle: angular is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to override, just include the necessary locale and then try.
See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/60/). I've tried with different directive, hope it helps :)

Include locale :

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.4/i18n/angular-locale_es-pe.js"></script>
```

Updated [Fiddler link.](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/61/)

Comment: Nice one anoop but I think the soles will be effect in ng-model. I need to show that soles symbol in screen only.It should not effect to ng-model

Comment: Anoop the old one is good. In the new one there is symbol missed in view but it is effecting in ng-model

Comment: no ng-model is not effected. I checked the same, it's only formatted [See this](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/19/)

Comment: Anoop here it is working fine but when we modify existing value then it is effecting to ng-model

Comment: please clarify and explain your problem with more details, as your question asked doesn't state any particular scenario. It seems I've not got your problem.

Comment: Anoop you are only the resoure I found in the entire internet. Because It is newest requirement.Anyway I have edited questing Please find it

Comment: I tried to understand your problem statement, here I'm giving you this [fiddler link](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/60/), I tried to address as much of I could by understanding your problem. But some of the error handling needs to be done as per your project structure. I hope this will help you to solve your problem. (I used soles as default currency and $ as optional.)

Comment: Annop I accepted your answer but it is till effecting to my ng-model when i modify the existing value

Comment: Annop have you found that issue

Comment: Please observe with console.log(); with submit button. In the view it is showing fine but the console contains soles symbol

Comment: I observe this behavior, It is due to angular digest cycle is not run for the first time because `element(blur)` event is outside the angular scope, but when you click submit button second time it runs(check with the previous fiifdle again). So you need to run digest cycle manually. Here's the [fiddler.](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/61/)

Comment: yes anoop that is what I want. But How can I call that directive for eachtime. I mean before calling any event's like ng-change,...

Comment: Here Is the https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/70/ which will call each time.

Comment: anoop I have a small reqirement. I.e., In the text bol there is directive which we created and there is a function in onchange. So Function is calling first so ng-model contains symbol. I want to call that directive first then function so directive will remove the symbol