# Angular digest cycle is not run for the first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the [JSFIDDLE.](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/61/)

In the text box For the first time keypress the symbol is effecting to my ng-model because `element(blur)`. How can I remove that symbol for the first keypress itself.

```
app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: { 
        val : '=val'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

            if (!ctrl) return;
            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {

            if(attrs.symbol == '$')
             return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue, '$')
             else
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });
            elem.bind('blur', function(event) {

            var a = elem.val();            
            var plainNumber = a.split('.').filter(function(e){
                return (e.length > 0);            
            }).join('.');
            var i = 0;
            if(isNaN(parseFloat(plainNumber))){
            i = (attrs.symbol == '$') ? 1 : 3;
            }
            var num = plainNumber.substring(i, plainNumber.length).replace(/,/g,'');
            if(attrs.symbol == '$')
            elem.val($filter('currency')(num, attrs.symbol));
            else
              elem.val($filter('currency')(num));                
            var n =parseFloat(num);
            scope.val = Number(n);
            if(!scope.$$phase) {
                scope.$apply();
             }
            });
        }
    };

    // controller 
}])
```

when keypress the symbol is effecting to ng-model. when I give click on outside then the symbol is not effecting to ng-model. I want to remove this symbol for the first keypress it self

I am new to angularjs. Please help me.

**Update:**

When Entering into the text box the ng-model containing symbol. when I click outside of textbox then it is removing the symbol and not effecting to ng-model. What I want is, when entering value only ng-model should not contain that symbol.

Comment: Didn't get you? can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Sravan I have edited the question

Comment: @Shiva, I think you refer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999195/how-to-apply-formatted-mask-to-a-input-filed/43003552#43003552), where symbol was required but for your problem. Do you need symbol at all for input box ? or just no symbolin input mask ?